# How to change text opacity using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, text, textbox, opacity

I need help in changing opacity of text in textbox.As of now I'm able to change the textbox opacity but I need to change text opacity inside textbox

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Step 1: set up the slider with some options. The valid values for opacity are 0 to 1
        //Step 2: Bind an event so when you slide the slider and stop, the following function gets called
        $('#slider').slider({ min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.1, value: 1 })
            .bind("slidechange", function () {
                //get the value of the slider with this call
                var o = $(this).slider('value');
                //here I am just specifying the element to change with a "made up" attribute (but don't worry, this is in the HTML specs and supported by all browsers).
                var e = '#' + $(this).attr('data-wjs-element');
                $(e).css('opacity', o)
            });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my textbox

```
<div id="slider" data-wjs-element="TextBox1"></div>

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: can you show more of the client side code? It's hard to tell exactly what you want to change with your two snippets. The text box shown here doesn't have the property you look for to use in the opacity setting.

Comment: There is nothing more than this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use rgba for color but IE8 and below doesn't support it. Also some older versions of other browsers doesn't support. You can find information from [here](http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/).

```
$(e).css('color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + o + ')');
```

BTW your "made up" attribute is [part of HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) :) You can access it's value like this;

```
$(this).data('wjs-element');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and If I change to the above code as you mentioned it dosen't show me any opacity.

Comment: I updated my answer. The code below is not related with your problem. It's a hint. I added another code piece which is related with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update and It has problem with IE8 as you mentioned and it is fine with the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with:

```
$(e).fadeTo(0, o);
```

?

Comment: Yes I have done it and it changes the opacity for the entire textbox.